# Item vertical scroll interferes with carousel horizontal scroll (Android only)

Tags: react-native, react-native-snap-carousel

I have a carousel (using `react-native-snap-carousel`) where each item is a card that has a title and a WebView. On Android, when attempting to scroll the web page loaded in the webview, the gesture handler of the Carousel gets fired first most of the time. On iOS, everything works fine.

So on Android it's virtually impossible to scroll the webpage vertically without triggering the horizontal Carousel scroll.

I have created a small Demo project where you can see the issue

https://github.com/dudeinthemirror/carousel-example

The question is: is there a way to fix this behavior for Android?
Thanks for your time